# Android perform ImageUpload in background and access intent data in callback

Tags: android, service, android-intentservice

Well I've thinking through this problem and i need some help from community.

I want to upload image(s)(5 images) to server which is currently done in async task of app. Hence upload can be stopped when user closes the app so i want to perform this operation using `IntentService`.

So I have created my Intent Service to perform image upload.

```
  public class ImageUploadService extends IntentService {


    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
     * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
     */
    public ImageUploadService(String name) {super(name);}

    public ImageUploadService(){
        this(ImageUploadService.class.getName());
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        //todo perform long running image upload operation

        KbUserService kbUserService = JacksonRestRequestBuilder
                .setupUploadRestService(RestUrls.BASE_URL_CUSTOMER, true,
                        KbUserService.class, getApplicationContext());

        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> requestBody = new LinkedHashMap<>();


        Call<LinkedHashMap<String,Object>> call = kbUserService.uploadFile(requestBody);

        call.enqueue(new KbCallback() {
            @Override
            public void failure(Map<String, Object> serverErrorResponse, String genericErrorMessage) {
                //todo send notification that image upload failed and also send broadcast event that image upload failed.
            }

            @Override
            public void success(Map<String, Object> successResponse) {

                Map<String, Object> modelDataFromResponseAsMap =
                        ClientModelUtils.getModelDataFromResponseAsMap(successResponse);
//                    Log.i(NAME,"Background Image upload completed for "+msg.arg1);
                String fileUrl = ClientModelUtils.getString(modelDataFromResponseAsMap,
                        ModelConstants.UserConstants.IMAGE_URL);
                //todo send notification that image upload success and send broadcast that image upload success.
//                    uploadFileSuccess(fileUrl, profName);
//                    bean.setUploadInProgress(false);
//                    view.uploadFileSuccess(fileUrl,profName);
            }

            @Override
            public void networkOrUnexpectedError(String message) {
                //todo send notification that image upload failed and also send broadcast event that image upload failed.
            }
        });

    }

    protected void showToast(final String msg){
        //gets the main thread
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // run this code in the main thread
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

So here i send a broadcast in success response to all registered activities.

I'm not able to solve the following problems,

1.Suppose when came out of app and came back to activity, how to know what are the currently uploading images?

2.How to access intent data in `onHandleIntent()` inside callback?, Because in intent data i have information about the `imageType` so when request is success i want to send an broadcast with `imageUrl` and `imageType`.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the ideal answer but I normally have broadcast receivers on both the service and the activity. This way they can communicate with each other. For example when the activity starts again I send a broadcast to the service notifying it. The service will then send a broadcast with its information.

```
public class SomeService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(SOME_SERVICE_ACTIONS));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            switch (intent.getIntExtra(SERVICE_COMMAND, 0)) {
                case ACTIVITY_STARTED:
                    sendCallback();

                break;
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: How do identify the current executing tasks? and also how can you access intent data inside callback?

Comment: You should keep your intent data as a field. As for the currently uploading task, you will have to look that up on the library you're using. If you can get a callback from that you will be able to broadcast that information.